# PHP - Redirect website with information

Tags: php, html, redirect

I would like to redirect a user to a website with showing an information "Redirecting... Please wait" in the website. What is the fastes way to do that? I can use HTML and PHP.

Comment: The fastest way to do it is to **not** delay them by showing them a redirecting message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give a try to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Moved</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL='http://www.example.com/'" />    
</head>
<body>
    <p>This page has moved to <a href="http://www.example.com/">www.example.com</a>.</p>
    <p>You will be redirected within 3 seconds.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with `php`, you can use the header() function to send a new HTTP header, but this must be sent to the browser before any HTML or text (even before the  declaration, ).

```
header('Location: '.$newURL);
die();
```

Or you try something like this involving redirect status codes - 301,302 etc

```
function Redirect($url, $permanent = false)
{
  if (headers_sent() === false)
    {
       header('Location: ' . $url, true, ($permanent === true) ? 301 : 302);
       die();
    }

 exit();
}

Redirect('http://www.example.com/', false);
```

---

else It's easily possible with html

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL='http://www.example.com/' />
```

Here `content` is number of secods you want to delay.`

Comment: Nice, but I answered exactly the same thing two minutes ago, wise guy.

Comment: @MightyPork: I didn't see your answer it was not loaded yet. btw, i am editing my answer.